# split / manipulate pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

i need help ... I have folowing column `abcdefghi` or `abcdefghijkl` or `abcdefghijklmno`
I need following output: `abc-def def-ghi` or `abc-def def-ghi ghi-jkl` or `abc-def def-ghi ghi-jkl jkl-mno`

to split the column I use :

```
def split_chunk(txt, n=3):
    return [txt[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(txt), n)]

df=pd.DataFrame(df.COLUMN.apply(split_chunk).to_list())
```

```
    1   2   3   4   5
0   abc def ghi
1   abc def ghi jkl
2   abc def ghi jkl
3   abc def ghi jkl mno
4   abc def ghi
5   abc def ghi
```

to receive multiple columns with my split value ... how can I merge this to my desired output?

```
0   abc-def     def-ghi
1   abc-def     def-ghi     ghi-jkl
2   abc-def     def-ghi     ghi-jkl
3   abc-def     def-ghi     ghi-jkl     jkl-mno
4   abc-def     def-ghi
5   abc-def     def-ghi
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest solution is modify your `split_chunk` function to produce the data you want directly:

```py
def split_chunk(txt,n=3):
   return [txt[i:i+n]+'-'+txt[i+n:i+2*n] for i in range(0, len(txt)-n, n)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'COLUMN': ['abcdefghi','abcdefghijkl','abcdefghijklmno']})
df = pd.DataFrame(df.COLUMN.apply(split_chunk).to_list())
df
```

Output:

```
         0        1        2        3
0  abc-def  def-ghi     None     None
1  abc-def  def-ghi  ghi-jkl     None
2  abc-def  def-ghi  ghi-jkl  jkl-mno
```